# Rails STI Mystery - Why does type change from Class to String in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

This is long so I hope you'll bear with me...

I have a model called Update with two subclasses, MrUpdate and TriggeredUpdate. Using single-table inheritance, added type field as a string to Update.

In my view I'm checking which type it is to decide what to display. I assumed since type is a string, I should do

```
<% if @update.type == 'MrUpdate' %>
```

This failed, i.e., it evaluated to false when the update was an MrUpdate. I noticed that at this point, @update.type.type is Class. OK, whatever, thought I, so I changed it to:

```
<% if @update.type == MrUpdate %>
```

and it worked, i.e., the comparison evaluated to true when the update was an MrUdpate. Then I did it again lower down in my view and it failed again (i.e., it evaluated to false when the update was an MrUpdate.)

Turns out the culprit is a couple of <%= link_to ... %> calls I use and make into buttons with jQuery. If I put this code in my view:

```
<br>
<%=  @update.type.type %><br>
<%=  @update.type %><br>

<%= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path(:update_id => @update.id), :class => "ui-button" %>

<br>
<%=  @update.type.type %><br>
<%=  @update.type %><br>
```

What I see is:

```
Class
MrUpdate

(the New Note button)

String
MrUpdate
```

It's changing from a class to a string! So what the heck am I doing wrong or missing here? Why should a link_to do that? First I'm not clear why it's not a string in the first place, but then really confused as to why it would change...?!? Any help or explanation would be helpful. I can just code it one way at the top and another way at the bottom, but that way madness lies. I need to understand why this is happening.

Comment: don't you think that `type` is a kind of reserved word?

Comment: Yes, and it's reserved for this purpose. Having MrUpdate and TriggeredUpdate derive from Update and adding the type field to Update is how you do single table inheritance, from what I've read.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue is here. Thanks to fl00r for pointing the way.

Yes, type is a reserved in Ruby 1.8.7 which tells you the class of the object you call it from. But it's also true that it is the name of the field used in Rails to indicate single-table inheriance and to store the name of the class of each instance of the subclass.

So I naively tried to access the value of the type field using @update.type. But what this was doing at the top of the view was calling the type method of the Object class in Ruby. For whatever reason, after the link_to calls, it was then access the value of the type field of the updates table.

While trying to figure this out I called @update.type in the Rails console and saw this message: "warning: Object#type is deprecated; use Object#class". Finally it registered what I was doing. When I changed my calls to:

```
<% if @update.class == MrUpdate %>
```

everything works as expected. I never saw a call to determine the type in any of the pages I found via Google about STI. This despite the fact that they all recommended using only one controller, wherein sometimes you must need to determine the class of the instance you have.

So, dumb mistake--pilot error. But maybe this will help someone else who gets tripped up on this.